# Check if Canvas Child exist: by tag

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I can check by tag if a `Canvas` child exists?

For example I want to know if in my `Canvas` (canvas1) there exists a child that has tag "p".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I can check by tag if a canvas child exist?

So I suppose a bool value is what you want

```
bool result = mycanvas.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                      .Any(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "p");
```

I used `(x.Tag == null ? "" : x.Tag.ToString()) == "p")` just to be sure that tag property is not null.

OR

If you want the Element then

```
FrameworkElement result = mycanvas.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                                           .Where(x => x.Tag != null && 
                                                  x.Tag.ToString() == "p")
                                           .First();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            object mytag;
            DrawingCanvas.Children.Select((elem) =>
            {
                FrameworkElement fe = elem as FrameworkElement;
                if (fe != null)
                {
                    return fe.Tag == mytag;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            });
```